# JSDock - Documentation for anonymus arrrow function parameter

Tags: javascript, parameters, documentation, arrow-functions, jsdoc3

I have a function which gets an arrow function parameter, and i need to describe it.

```
/**
 * Some awesome descriptions
 * @param {Object} param - param
 * @param {string} param1 - param1 
 * @param {function} func - function
*/
function function(param, param1, func) {
   ...
}
```

My problem is, that I cant describe parameters of the `func`. I already tried to use [callbacks](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-callback.html) and [types](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-type.html), but i cant achive it works.

I call this function like

```
function({foo:bar}, 'call', foo => foo + 1)
```